# blending of alteryx's output with tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Whether the Data output from Alteryx can be mapped to Tableau Reports directly or do we need to store the Data output in an intermediate Database (like SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

Altyryx can generate a Tableau data extract or write to a relational database. Tableau can read from either format. Your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can publish from Alteryx to Tableau go to Connector and then select "Publish to Tableau Server Tool" if you don't to have the tool. download it from here:
[Click Here](https://gallery.alteryx.com/#!app/Publish-to-Tableau-Server-Tool/599c93c8f499c7141c13a619)